# How to use send_keys in selenium webdriver in python?

Tags: python, selenium

i want to move the canvas element using mouse right click and mouse move. how can i do with it actiondriver and send_keys in selenium. could someone help me with this. thanks.

i have tried something like

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(canvas_element).send_keys(
Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ADD)).build().perform();
```

this is to zoomin the canvas element. similarly how can i perform right click and mouse move.

Comment: What code have you tried? You are much more likely to get an answer if you provide your attempts (no matter how bad), and the desired outcome of your code.

Comment: updated my question. thanks

Comment: Can you provide the website and element that you are trying this on?  Your code as is looks fine, but I can't say for sure without looking at the page.

Comment: my code in the question works for zooming in the canvas_element. how can i do right click and drag on canvas element using the selenium in python. thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium webdriver sendkeys() using python and firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564539/selenium-webdriver-sendkeys-using-python-and-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `context_click` in [selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html) for right click.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

actionChains.context_click(your_link).perform()
```

With Selenium Webdriver, you can move mouse using `move_by_offset(xoffset, yoffset)` function

Reference - https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html?highlight=mouse#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset